# select all nodes with information using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Using XPath, what is a good command to select all nodes in a document that contain information...

```
 //text()
```

selects all the text, but no tags with it, and I get major gaps

```
  //comment()
```

selects the comment section

any ideas would be great

**EDIT for formatting purposes **

I have an XML file which consists of places in the world. so its broken down kind of like this

```
     <Place id="USA">
      <name>USA</name>
      <econ>
          <crops>corn</crops>
          <travel></travel>
       </econ>
     </place>
```

This is a very crude example but as you can see travel does not have any text attached to it, nor does place, or econ. I need a xpath statement that would display something like this given the above code

```
      Name=USA
      Crops=Corn
```

skipping place, econ, and travel because it does not contain text.

Comment: Can you elaborate "information" in your question?

Comment: I have an XML file which consists of places in the world. so its broken down kind of like this

     <Place id="USA">
          <name>USA</name>
          <econ>
              <crops>corn</crops>
              <travel></travel>
This is a very crude example but as you can see travel does not have any text attached to it, nor does place, or econ. I need a xpath statement that would display something like this given the above code

Name=USA
Crops=Corn

skipping place, econ, and travel because it does not contain text.

Comment: see above for proper look to xml code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//*[normalize-space(text())]
```

In your case it will return two nodes: `name` and `crops`